# Kendo combobox bound to odata not looking up text for value set

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a standard kendo web combo box that is bound to an odata data source. It looks up fine if you type into it and gets the right text and value.

However if you have it bound, and you set the .value() property in code, the text does not get looked up for the value that was set. (pretty standard behavior if you're loading existing data)

I would have assumed that it would have gone to the server and looked up by the dataValueField property for the exact value and returned the item specifically and set the text.

How do I go about making it do this?

Answer (score 3):

Lets have the following `ComboBox`:

```
var combobox = $("#combobox").kendoComboBox({
    dataTextField : "ProductName",
    dataValueField: "ProductID",
    dataSource    : {
        type     : "odata",
        transport: {
            read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Products"
        }
    }
}).data("kendoComboBox");
```

(You can use it yourself since it refers to a service available in Kendo UI servers).

Then you can use the following pieces of code for setting the `value` or the `text` (whatever you prefer).

```
// Set value of the ComboBox using dataValueField (ProductId)
combobox.value(4);
// Set value of the ComboBox using dataTextField (ProductName)
combobox.text("Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning");
```

And for reading you should use:

```
alert("Current text/value: " + combobox.text() + "/" + combobox.value());
```

Both methods work fine as you can check in here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/64gXE/.

Comment: Add: 

        serverPaging: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        pageSize: 3,

to the data source so that you're not defeating the purpose of odata by returning everything.

Now you'll notice that when you set the value to 4 it just shows the text "4" instead of looking up the value that it doesn't have yet with an odata command as it should have.

Everything works great if the data source has that value in it's data cache, but as soon as it doesn't, the control isn't loading it automatically like it should.

Comment: From your original questions, it seems to me that you only know the `value` but not the `text`. Is that the case? If you also know the text, you can use `combobox.search("Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning");`

Comment: I don't. The combo/drop down controls should automatically take a value given to it, look it up in the datasource. If the data source can't find it in it's current data set, it should look in it's cache of previous requests for the same key. If it still can't find it, it should do a lookup automatically with a $filter. It should look at the value that was set and determine if it's guid, string or number and format the $filter clause appropriately. This should happen automatically if serverfiltering:true.  I'm hoping someone has some ideas on how to work around this deficiency...

Comment: *bump* Anyone have any ideas on how to force load the correct data object that should automatically be loaded in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You have to really kick this thing in the a** to get get it working. There are a million configurations, of which only a few seem to work

WebAPI OData implementation (4.5) and Telerik Datasource really don't play well together. Here's my working client side ComboBox implementation:

```
$("#dropdownlist").kendoComboBox({
                    optionLabel: " ",
                    dataTextField: "name",
                    dataValueField: "id",
                    dataSource: {
                        serverFiltering: true,
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: "/odata/MyService",
                                'type': 'Get'
                            }
                        },
                        schema: {
                            parse: (response: any) => {
                                var results = response.value;
                                var items: any = [];
                                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                                    items.push(
                                        {
                                            id: results[i].id,
                                            name: results[i].name,
                                        });
                                }
                                return items;
                            },
                        }
                    }
                });
```

You'll notice that I have to hijack the data in the parse method in the schema object and massage it

My OData response for reference:

[image]

Comment: Sorry - this is a typescript implementation - remove the ": any" for vanilla javascript

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when re-binding a kendo combobox.  Basically I had to re-query the server as if the user had typed it in. Then once the query completes I select the correct item using the value previously chosen.

```
var comboBoxElem = $("#controlNameHere");

comboBoxElem.kendoComboBox(
    {
        placeholder: "Start typing...",
        dataTextField: "yourDataTextField",     // field used in the re-query due to 'contains' filter
        dataValueField: "yourDataValueField",
        filter: "contains",
        change: selectFunc,
        dataSource: {
            serverFiltering: true,
            pageSize: 20,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "http://yourUrlHere"
                }
            }
        }
    });


// the following code is all about re-selecting the previous value

var comboBox = comboBoxElem.data('kendoComboBox');

var previousTextValue = 'text of the previous entry here';
var previousValue = '543';

comboBox.text(previousTextValue);   // to show the user text while re-query takes place

// reload previous item(s) from server, then re-select the desired item

comboBox.dataSource.query({
    filter: { operator: "contains", field: 'yourDataTextField', value: previousTextValue },
    complete: function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            comboBox.select(function (dataItem) {
                return dataItem.yourDataValueField == previousValue;
            });
        }, 200);  //allow the observable collection to be updated (no event I know of helps here :(
    }
});
```

Hopefully this is clear enough, I have modified the code inline to protect the inocent so there may be the slightest syntax error.

Keep in mind the filter you use in the options (setup) of the control should be the same you use to re-query for simplicity, otherwise you will get multiple filters coming through to the server.